# No Settings for SMTP module

Tags: 7

I installed [SMTP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) for Drupal 7.
I enabled it and press Settings button to go to Settings menu.
But there is no Setting menu there...
How to reach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SMTP module configuration page is at `admin/config/system/smtp`.

Make sure that you have the permission change the SMTP configuration.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have such page. I checked permissions - all is OK for admin.

Comment: Are you using D7 ? What version of the SMTP module are you using ? Did you try clear the caches ?

Comment: Yes, it is Drupal 7. I tried both vertions - stable and dev. I cleared cashes.

Comment: Do you have any logs ? From admin/reports/dblog.

Comment: Yes, I found there errors with 1 of my views. I made it disabled and after that Settings for SMTP appears. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @user38998 We can't have idea why without knowing your view. Conflicting paths, maybe?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Error was in conflicting path (in pages). I have in one page path /For tabs and in 2 another pages path /for tabs. ANd first tab (/For path) was marked as conflicted. It is strange, because when I disabled it, I got 2 pages with the same path (/for tabs) but no conflict for them....

Answer (score 0):

It was error in Views page - conflicting path. To find it I checked report page.
After fixing this problem, Settings menu for SMTP module appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download [SMTP](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) module and enable it.

Step 2: Go to Admin > Configuration > System > SMTP authentication support and set the following [values](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13287):

- Turn this module on or off: On.
- SMTP server settings:

  - smtp server: smtp.gmail.com
  - smtp backup server: leave blank.
  - smtp port: 465
  - use encrypted protocol: select "use SSL"
- SMTP authentication:

  - Enter a valid Gmail email address and password.
- Email options:

  - Set the same email address that you used at SMTP Authentication.
- Send test email: set an email to receive a sample email and to test whether the module is working.
- Enable debugging: yes.

Step 2a(Optional): [Allow Less Secure Apps Access](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) which is here: http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Step 3: Click on Save and go to your inbox to check. If there is an testing email then it is fine.

Note: Your email address provided in your smpt setting MUST be the same like in your site information.